# How to transfer a list between BackgroundWorker_DoWork, and _RunWorkerCompleted

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, backgroundworker

I have a background worker procedure which fires when the `PhoneApplicationPage` has `Loaded`.

How do I transfer a list generated in the _DoWork procedure to the _RunWorkerComplete procedure?

Here's the empty code: (I would put it all in but it's quite long)

```
private void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = false;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = false;

    bw.RunWorkerCompleted +=
new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bw_RunWorkerCompleted);
    }

private void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: You can check this out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx

Comment: didn't really contain anything on the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set `e.Result` in the `DoWork` handler and read `e.Result` in the `RunWorkerCompleted` handler (you'll need to cast it back to the appropriate type).

Other options are to use an instance field of the type; set it in one and read it in the other, or to have both event handlers being lambdas, rather than named methods, in which they both close over some common variable(s).